Multiple robots.txt Files Causing Sitemap Blockage - Need Support
I'm encountering an unusual issue with multiple robots.txt files on a site I'm managing. When trying to update one of the robots.txt files and requesting the removal of the old one via Google Search Console, I found that the sitemap is being blocked by one of the robots.txt files.
Has anyone faced this before or have any advice on how to resolve this? I’m looking for a smart solution to handle this without disrupting the site's indexing. Any support or guidance would be appreciated!

